# Enable md-checkbox when option from md-radio-button was selected

Tags: angularjs

I have to choose only one option and only activate their respective extra fields. (see image)

[image: Form]

I tried the same with "radio-button" but I cannot detect when it is changed. Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

You can do with ng-change()

**HTML:**

```
  <md-radio-group ng-change="test()" ng-model="myVar">
    <md-radio-button value="One">One</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button value="Two">Two</md-radio-button>
    <md-radio-button value="Three">Three</md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
```

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.test = function(){
      alert("test");
  }
```

In the sample checkbox will be enabled when user selects value as **One**

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Q4VNsX?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-disabled like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" placeholder="Disabled if not checked"> <input type="text" ng-disabled="!checked">
```

That will disable the input if the checkbox is not clicked.

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/bi0IFnuid7rQA112jSsc?p=preview)